# UpdateProgress not appearing on second click of same button

Tags: c#, updatepanel, updateprogress

UpdateProgress appear first time, when i click on the button btnSubmit. But when i click the same button next time UpdateProgress not appearing. But all other things works well. I am using this UpdateProgress to show a GIF image while sending E-mail to client. For the first client UpdateProgress appear but for second to other 'n' UpdateProgress not appearing. Please help i am asking this question Second time in Stack Overflow

Code below shows my UpdateProgress

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress"
                runat="server">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div class="modal">
                        <div class="center">
                            <span style="padding-left: 10px"><b>Please Wait..</b></span>
                            <img alt="" src="../images/Preloader_3.gif" width="50" height="50" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code below shows my button that trigger the UpdateProgress

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                    OnClientClick="javascript:return btnSubmit();" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                    runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                <a href="assignment.aspx?sid=<%=Request.QueryString["sid"] %>" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind CS

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updProgress.Visible = true;
        SendEmail(Convert.ToInt32(drpDiv.Text));
        updProgress.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place your update progress outside the update panel and associate with update progress. You can create another update panel to trigger your button with auto post back true.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
                    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
<ProgressTemplate>
    <!-- Place your Message here -->
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack="true" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <!-- You can put some controls here -->
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Or, second method is:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" 
                    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <!-- Place your Message here -->
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack="true" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: @Asid.Ali  i modified my code as above second method but no use . Still i am in trouble . Thank you for your  reply

Comment: @Asid.Ali  I found the problem is, second time if i upload a file the UpdateProgress not works . else it appears . that is if i click btnsubmit without upload a image the updateprogress works .. Can you help me

Comment: You have also create a postbacttrigger  and give ID your `FileUpload` control and its event name.

Comment: error found as postbacttrigger is not valid attribute

Comment: Asyn or non-asyn. I think it should be non-asyn trigger??

Comment: @Asid.Ali <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgPhoto" />
    </Triggers> is it correct  ??

Comment: yeh try it and inform me

Comment: error :- Control with ID 'imgPhoto' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or RegisterPostBackControl must implement either INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, or IPostBackEventHandler.

Comment: give it an `EventName` to it.

Comment: error :- Type 'System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger' does not have a public property named 'EventName'. code <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgPhoto" EventName="Click" />

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="imgPhoto" runat="server" /> Yes

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="imgPhoto" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="**btnUpload**" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"  /> Sorry for my mistake you mean btnUpload. But event name is not a valid attribute for PostBackTrigger

Comment: Ali  Got the result when i remove the visibility control from the code behind . Thank u for your support